# php tags with regex preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a url let's say : https://stackoverflow.com/example1/
and images tags

```
<img f="/example2"></img>
<img f="example3"></img>
<img f="http://example4.com"></img>
<img f="https://example5.com"></img>
```

and here is my regex code for preg_replace:

```
$regex = "-(src\s*=\s*['\"])(((?!'|\"|http://|https://).)*)(['\"])-i";
```

so if I use this code in the tags above the output will be :

```
<img f="https://stackoverflow.com/example1//example2></img>
<img f="https://stackoverflow.com/example1/example3></img>
<img f="http://example4.com/"></img>
<img f="https://example5.com/"></img>
```

but what I want is /example2 and example3 get replaced too but for /example2 it gets only https://stackoverflow.com/ and for example3 it gets https://stackoverflow.com/example1 
ps : I know how to get domain using parse_url. and f= is src ^^

Comment: Not sure I'm following you but what about,  `f="(?!https?://)/?(.*?)"`? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/217d5b5c1433cf5d3c60a4c041ca10370edbebc1 I used `f` in regex because that is what your samples used.

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for , let's say I want if src doesn't have a / at start then we will add the url http://stackoverflow.com/example1 at start?